# Who is this red coated magician in “Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems”?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, video-games

There is a point in the SNES game [Marvel Super Heroes In War of the Gems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_In_War_of_the_Gems) where you arrive at a volcano, and the only way to proceed forward is to fly over the magma field.

At that point in the game, some kind of red coated magician appears, levitating above the magma. Then he uses his power to create a flying platform for us to stand on, after which he simply teleports away.

[image: Screenshot depicting Iron Man standing on the left next to a magma field, with a red coated magician floating above the magma on the right]

This is the only time we see that character in the entire game, and he does not say a single word, he simply spawns a platform to help us.

Who is he?

Comment: Looks like Dr. Strange to me.

Comment: What's wrong with the default assumption that it's Dr. Strange?  Giant collar and reddish cloak...

Comment: As strange as this may sound, I never heard about Dr. Strange before, so I thought I might as well ask, because image search didn't wield any result.

Comment: @DavidW - I refuse to post it as an answer without proof. I mean, c'mon, it's clearly him. But prove it.

Comment: I mean, the only other red coated magician in that game is named "Adam Warlock", and he's got blond hair, so I was like: "That can't be him, is it... ?"

Comment: @Clockwork - I still like proof. Just pointing at a thing and saying "here's an unsourced wiki that says it's him" is pretty weak sauce as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Valorum I found a couple of play-throughs that identified him, plus identification of that specific image on a fandom page for the game, but nothing, you know, *canonical*.

Comment: @Valorum Hmm... Yeah. I think it's mostly the picture in the answer that I find relevant. The following stuffs look similar: big red coat with yellow edges, yellow waistcoat, white shirt, mustache, and white pattern in the hair.

Comment: @DavidW - I'll also a bounty on this one for anyone who can actually prove it. With first-hand evidence. Not wiki nonsense.

Comment: @Valorum I think I can also recognise the bottom "horn" like pattern of the waistcoat, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Having watched the movies... the only character with a cloak that floats... Dr Strange

Comment: @WernerCD Not true even for the movies; there's Vision, one could argue Thor but I suppose he more flies than floats and there's also Scarlet Witch but it's generally a long coat not a cloak.

Comment: A Google search for "marvel red-coated magician" does lead me to Dr. Strange fairly quickly. [The Fandom wiki for the game](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes:_War_of_the_Gems) also mentions him having a cameo.

Comment: Cloak of Levitation?  Check.  Eye of Agamotto?  Check. Goatee?  Check.  It’s Dr. Strange.  The Cloak in particular  is easily distinguished from all other cloaks in the Marvel Universe, and only Dr. Strange wears it.

Comment: I believe this is a use of the Lucy Lawless principle. “Where’d this floor come from?” “Wizard did it”.

Comment: @WernerCD Also this game long predates any of the MCU movies, so the source would have to be from the comics, and there's hundreds (thousands maybe?) of characters in the comics that haven't yet featured in any movie, so that's not quite enough to narrow it down.

Comment: Isn't it ironic that someone with an account name @CLOCKwork hasn't heard of the carrier of the Time Stone?

Comment: @Righter You know, you're right-er. Okay, I'm out.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe that is Dr. Strange with the look he had in the comics circa 1996, the year the game was released.

[image: Cover page for Doctor Strange Sorcerer Supreme Vol 1 #82. We can notice the similarities with the screenshot's magician, between the coat, the goatee, the haircut (with white hair pattern) and also what looks like a yellow waistcoast]

<sub>*[Doctor Strange, Sorcerer Supreme Vol 1 #82](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange,_Sorcerer_Supreme_Vol_1_82)*</sub>

[This page](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes:_War_of_the_Gems) lists him as having a cameo in the game.

Strange also had a supporting role in the various Infinity Gem-related mini-series' published during the 1990s, such as *[Infinity Gauntlet](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet_(Event))* and *[Infinity War](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_War_Vol_1)*, and the game appears to draw heavily on these storylines for inspiration.

[image: A page depicting Dr. Strange's involvement in Infinity Gauntlet Vol 1; he's seen aiding the heroes (Captain America, Spider-Man, Wolverine, Silver Surfer, etc.) for an upcoming battle]

<sub>*[Infinity Gauntlet Vol 1 #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet_Vol_1_3)*</sub>

[image: A page depicting Dr. Strange's involvement in Infinity War Vol 1]

<sub>*[Infinity War Vol 1 #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_War_Vol_1_4)*</sub>

Comment: Suddenly, I feel very stupid for not trying to search the game on the wikia page.

Comment: Also the TVTropes page for the game lists Doctor Strange's cameo (under the heading "The Cameo").  https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Videogame/MarvelSuperHeroesWarOfTheGems

Comment: This is the kind of situation I wish I could accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 21):

That’s Doctor Stephen Strange, more specifically it is the [Earth-30847 version](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Stephen_Strange_(Earth-30847)). Here’s Strange as he appears in *Doctor Strange: Sorcerer Supreme* Issue 84, note it’s the same outfit.

[image: page from the above comic showing Strange’s matching outfit]

There doesn’t appear to be any (easily found) “canonical” evidence that this is Strange that I can find. However, lots of online guides and walkthroughs all identify him as Strange. And for interest [here’s the sprite sheet](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/marvelherogems/sheet/31850/) that someone uploaded online for the game that also identifies him as Strange.

[image: Strange sprite sheet]

The game’s [instruction manual](http://www.thevgatv.com/resources/SNES/SNES-Marvel-Super-Heroes.pdf) does not include anything about this character that I can see.

Comment: FWIW I was going to try and look through the game's files but I don't think the *.SMC file contains any names for the sprites, they're just located at addresses within it so that won't be helpful.